# How does the Sanctuary spell stack with the College of Glamour bard's Unbreakable Majesty feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, bard, stacking

The College of Glamour bard's Unbreakable Majesty feature (XGE, p. 14-15) has a similar effect to the *sanctuary* spell, although it requires a Charisma save instead of a Wisdom save.

If someone attacks a creature under the effects of both, does the attacker need to make both saves?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, they'll stack and require two saves

Unbreakable Majesty (Xanathar's 14) has no concentration requirement and is a different effect from Sanctuary. The main difference is that Sanctuary applies to all attacks and spells directed at the target (but not AOE) while Unbreakable Majesty is only against the first Attack of the turn.

**But you still need a cleric (unless you used Magical Secrets to get it)**

### Combining Effects

**CHA Fail, WIS Fail** - Must choose another creature to attack or lose attack/spell

**CHA Fail, WIS Pass** - Must choose another creature to attack or lose attack and gets Disadvantage on any saves against your spells next turn.

**CHA Pass, WIS Fail** - Must choose another creature to attack or lose attack

**CHA Pass, WIS Pass** - Can attack/cast spell at you. Receives disadvantage on any saves against your spells next turn.

### More than one attack?

Unbreakable Majesty is only active for the first attack on a turn. Any additional attacks or reactions taken during that turn will only save against Sanctuary.

### Can someone end those effects?

Sanctuary can be counterspelled before it starts or can be removed via Dispel Magic. Unbreakable Majesty is not a spell and is therefore immune to those tactics. It also is an ability based off your appearance and may also work in an Anti-magic field.

Comment: Another meaningful difference: Unbreakable Majesty can't be counterspelled, since it isn't a spell, per se.

Comment: Good answer, but Cleric and Magical Secrets are by no means the only ways - should probably scrap that potentially misleading line instead of listing any or all of the possibilities, which aren't strictly relevant to the question anyway.

Comment: AOE spells do target the creatures within the AOE so you could not cast one that targets a creature under the effect of *sanctuary*

Comment: The Unbreakable Majesty feature says "you assume a **magically** majestic presence..." Since it includes the word magically, I think the feature definitely would not work in an Anti-magic field.